# Defining Ruby on Rails Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, relationship

I have the following Models:

**Users:**

UserID, FirstName, LastName, State, Gender, Verified, UserTypeID

**Statuses:**

StatusID, Message, PostDate, UserID

**UserTypes**

UserTypeID, Description, Enabled

How would I appropriately associate these relationships? I have the Status one down, but not sure on the UserTypes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :statuses
    #AssociationToUserTypes
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
    #AssociationTouUsers
end
```

Is there anything in the migration I generate I need to declare as well?

Comment: can you give us more information about usertypes and how its related to the User

Comment: has_many is what you'd use if there are many rows associated with the object. If User can have Tasks (like an employee having many tasks to accomplish), then you'd use has_many :tasks, but I think OP might be using Status to store state. While there are many possible values for Status, each User really only has one Status.

Comment: @Eryc Brown A user can only be one user type. The UserType is at a very basic level, but it will house attributes of the users type (Right now just a description, Standard User, Administrator, Developer, etc.)

Comment: @MarsAtomic Status is just like a status post (Think Facebook). A User can have many statuses.

Comment: Yeah... has_many is wrong then. Give this [Rails Guide section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, foreigner_key: "UserTypeID"
end
```

Rails will try to find column with `user_type_id`, so we need to specify custom.

btw if you use rails generators it can be easier:

```
rails g model user first_name:string last_name:string state:string gender:boolean verified:boolean user_type:references
```

This command will generate migration, model, empty test file. You also can use CamelCase for column names.

Comment: Yeah, I used the generate scaffold technique but didn't have UserType setup at that point. Whats the generate migration for adding the UserTypes association?

Comment: `rails g migratio addBlaBlaToUsers user_type_id:integer`